# Iterating a list in a function

Tags: tcl

I am trying to print a list by passing it to a function:

```
set GPO_regs "0x70034 0x70038 0x7003C 0x70040 0x70044"

proc write_register {$regs $value} {
 puts [format "Value to be written at %s register is %s" $regs $value]
}

foreach regs $GPO_regs {write_register $regs 0x0000}
```

But I am getting an error:

```
can't read "regs": no such    variable
```

Comment: You might benefit from reading through the Tcl tutorial. There's a link here: http://www.tcl.tk/doc/

Answer (score 1):

Got the answer, '$' should be removed from the arguments:

```
   proc write_register {regs value} {
```